# Print to Android Device over the Network

Tags: android, printing, windows-xp, port, network-printers

Is it possible for an Android phone running Jelly Bean to emulate a network discover-able printer?

The goal of the application on the phone is to emulate a printer and have a Windows XP computer discover the printer over the network. I will add the printer and configure it with a generic text printer. When a file is sent over the network to the phone, an app will receive the file and store it as a file on the storage card.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: HP already had similar solution for their webos? I think there could already be applications in market which could be doing that. Should be possible to do as far as I understand

Comment: Could work if you write an app the responds correctly on the ports that network printers do. IDK if apps can open those ports though and it's going to be quite some work to emulate a printer